# Конвертирование 3D сцены в 2D сцену

Tags: wpf, 3d, xaml, c#

Ситуация следующая: имеется достаточно большая 3D модель системы, полученная конвертацией из 3DMax (размер xaml разметки больше 50мб). Для работы с моделью используется Viewport3D. Но для отображения нужен лишь фронтальный вид. Основной проблемой становится ресурсоемкость получающегося приложения.

Вопрос: существует ли способ для приведения 3D сцены к 2D виду? Желательно без существенной потери качества.

Comment: Что значит приведения? Отрисовать видимую область и реализовать удаление невидимых поверхностей? Статическая картинка не подойдет? Я не совсем понимаю, почему нельзя отрисовать сцену из установленной как вам нужно камеры и сохранить в графическом виде, потому что тянуть 50 мб за собой - это не айс... Может присутствует анимация, динамические элементы, ...

Comment: Сохранить как статическую картинку нельзя, тк во время выполнения динамически подгружаются некоторые элементы общей сцены.
Под приведением понималось реализация фронтального вида в 2Д

Answer (score 6, accepted):

То что вы хотите нельзя сделать, кроме как превратив в статическое изображение. Рендеринг 3D-сцены - это и есть приведение к 2D. Единственное, что можно было бы сделать, это всё превратить в какой-нибудь флеш, который в принципе работает именно с 2D, но тогда все объекты по отдельности придётся как-то растеризовать или превращать в плоские векторные объекты. И не факт что это будет работать быстрее, или что это будет меньше весить.

Answer (score 0):

***XAML файлы*** - это некомпилированные Baml. Может стоит создать алгоритм их хранения в бинарном виде вроде отдельного файла, который можно прочитать и отправить в Viewport3D. Еще скорее всего если детально просмотреть сохраненный результат из 3DMax`a, скорее всего он будет просто ужасным. Здесь тоже можно кое-что выкинуть. В любом случае нужно поработать ручками.

Comment: Вообще не ясно, как это может помочь решить задачу.